# Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel, phpexcel

I have used PHPExcel for my codeigniter app and it is working perfectly in localhost, but when I host this to server, I am getting following error :

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found in \xx\xx\xx
>   third_party\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php on line 36

Comment: Do you develop on windows and deploy to nix by any chance?

Comment: Is everything else working or..?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the complete phpExcel library structure to the live server

Comment: The problem here is inconsistencies between your local and production environments - you need to ensure that both environments meet your dependency requirements ie. make sure that all the required libraries are present and loaded.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I am using php 5.2.17

Comment: It's working fine in my local server

Answer (score 3):

There was a change introduced to the autoloader in the latest version of PHPExcel that appears to have broken backward compatibility with versions of PHP < 5.3.0

If you edit the `Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php` file and change line 58, which should read

```
return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'), true, true);
```

to

```
return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
```

I've already made a change to the develop branch on github to test for the PHP version and execute the appropriate line

While this was not deliberate, please note that we really are trying to get users to upgrade to at least version 5.3.0 of PHP, because we can't address any of the memory/performance issues that users working with large spreadsheets complain about until we can use some of the new features available in more recent versions of PHP. Version 5.2 of PHP is no longer supported, and even version 5.3 is end-of-life and will be unsupported before the end of this year

Comment: We're obsessed with it because it's so useful, when integrating with other libraries, when eliminating the need to include every single thing even when it isn't needed (to keep memory usage low)... and it doesn't mean adding new problems, unless people don't know what they're doing... and the autoloader means that you only need to include one php file

Comment: And this issues isn't an autoloader issue specificlly, it's a backward compatibility issue

Comment: autoloader solves a non-problem: a library may ships with tons of php files, it should have one file called include.php which includes its own files. In order to use such library just include that single file. Is that simple

Comment: Why do you then load every single individual file from that single included file, whether you need it or not? That's incredibly wasteful of memory, and highly inefficient.... an autoloader eliminates all that, only loading those files that are needed at the point when they are needed, so that "non-problem" of potentially excessive memory usage is significantly reduced

Comment: And as it stands, the PHPExcel library provides a single file to include that works with the autoloader.... so isn't that simple?

Comment: And the examples obviously aren't clear enugh in telling you that it's `Classes/PHPExcel.php`?

Comment: In C you can include the entire world but only the functions actually called by the program make their way to the linker and the final executable

Comment: C is a compiled language; PHP is a scripting language; you're comparing totally different fish... but perhaps if you think so little of PHP and so highly of C, you should just be coding in C and leave PHP alone

Comment: BTW, I had a non printable character in my php script file, I removed it and now the include works. I think PHPExcel is a great library but the documentation is really poor: the names of the example files are different, getActiveSheet() doesn't work anymore. I can't find the very basic and simple example of iterating the rows and the columns of a spreadsheet. I feel I'm learning the library by trial and error on StackOverflow. It happens the same for AngularJS

Comment: What do you expect the [Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) or [API Documentation](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/packages/PHPExcel.html) to have that it doesn't have? Or the examples to demonstrate different features? The`names of the example files are different` are different to what? `getActiveSheet()` works otherwise almost the entire library wouldn't work at all; iterating the rows/cells example is `28iterator.php`

Comment: And why does somebody with over 3k rep on SO hijack the comments of an answer to raise these issues?

Comment: because according to the SO rules there's no need to duplicate questions over and over, better attach to the comment thread

Comment: Well a rant against autoloaders wasn't really asking any question! It didn't tell me you were having problems with PHPExcel at all

Answer (score 1):

struggled with this issue for a long time under Linux and PHP 5.4x. In the end, in addition to the fix above, I resorted to changing the code on line 73 of the Autoloader file which sets the $pClassFilePath variable from relative (using PHPEXCEL_ROOT) to absolute following the machines file tree. This might only be a hack, but it saved my sanity after several days of trying. Hope this helps someone. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and i solved it by changing permissions on "Shared" directory to 655.

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If your server is on **Linux**, it can be permission problem... Just add all permissions for **PHPExcel** Folder in you Vendor (on server side) and **all subfolders** for it. I have same problem and i have solved it by this way...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing `PHPExcel/Autoloader.php` line 81 from

```
if ((file_exists($pClassFilePath) === FALSE) || (is_readable($pClassFilePath) === FALSE)) {
```

to

```
if ((stream_resolve_include_path($pClassFilePath) === FALSE)) {
```

I prefer this approach because it didn't require me to modify file permissions and it should work in PHP 5.3.2 and later.