# I have Error in my php auto loader file at the time of excel upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, export-to-excel

My code is working in local but when I upload my same code in live it gives me

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found
>
> Filename: /home/u451055217/domains/barque.online/public_html/demo/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php
>
> Line Number: 11

my auto load file:

```
<?php
PHPExcel_Autoloader::register();
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
PHPExcel_Shared_String::buildCharacterSets();

class PHPExcel_Autoloader
{
    public static function register()
    {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
            return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'load'), true, true);
        } else {
            return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'load'));
        }
    }

    public static function load($pClassName)
    {
        if ((class_exists($pClassName, false)) || (strpos($pClassName, 'PHPExcel') !== 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        $pClassFilePath = PHPEXCEL_ROOT .
            str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pClassName) .
            '.php';
        if ((file_exists($pClassFilePath) === false) || (is_readable($pClassFilePath) === false)) {
            return false;
        }
        require($pClassFilePath);
    }
}
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
I uploaded the same code of my local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel\_Shared\_String' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134842/fatal-error-class-phpexcel-shared-string-not-found)

Comment: @Gulshan I visit this link and watch all answer but not usefull

Comment: it could be an issue with your library due to missing files. Try with fresh download PHPExcel.